# Indexing According to Number in the Names of Objects in a List in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Apologies for my title not being the best. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:
I have a list:

```
list1 = [a0_something, a2_something, a1_something, a4_something, a3_something]
```

i have another list who entries are tuples including a name such as :

```
list2 = [(x1,y1,z1,'bob'),(x2,y2,z2,'alex')...]
```

the 0th name in the second list corresponds to a0_something and the name in the 1st entry of the second list corresponds to a1_something. basically the second list is in the write order but the 1st list isnt.

The program I am working with has a setName function I would like to do this

```
a0_something.setName(list2[0][4])
```

and so on with a loop.

So that I can really just say

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    a(i)_something.setName(list2[i][4])
```

Is there anyway I can refer to that number in the a#_something so that I can iterate with a loop?

Comment: What is the significance of the something part of the name? Why not have a dictionary of names or something...

Comment: I'm going to join in with the... why a list? If you are making it, then why not create a list as you want, or make a dictionary. How / where are you getting the contents (class objects) from?

Answer (score 3):

No.

Variable names have no meaning in run-time. (Unless you're doing introspection, which I guarantee you is something *you should not be doing*.)

Use a proper list such that:

```
lst = [a0_val, a1_val, a2_val, a3_val, a4_val]
```

and then address it by `lst[0]`.

Alternatively, if those names have meanings, use a dict where:

```
dct = {
    'a0' : a0_val,
    'a1' : a1_val,
    # ...
}
```

and use it with `dct['a0']`.

Answer (score 0):

The enumerate function lets you get the value and the index of the current item.  So, for your example, you could do:

```
for i, asomething in enumerate(list1):
    asomething.setName(list2[i][3])
```

Since your list2 is length 4, the final element is index 3 (you could also use -1)